# Search for a value in html with swift

Tags: html, swift, xcode, parsing

I started with an easy project to learn more about swift and Xcode.
So i started with project where I'd like to find a certain value on an website. I retrieved the html code so far but now I'd like to narrow it down to the value I'd like to see.

In this html i'd like to write the 9,62 into a variable. So I think I have to find the class, span and the text. What I found so far are tutorials to work with an html file...but that didn't help me with the code I have written so far as I don't want to store the html in a file.

```
    </div></div><div class="My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)" 
    data-reactid="18"><div class="" data-reactid="19"><span 
    class="Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)" 
    data-reactid="20">9.62</span>
```

This is the code i have done so far:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSoup

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let html = URL(string: "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LEO.DE?p=LEO.DE.tsrc=fin-srch")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: html!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let html = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print(html)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to get the value from html or set the value into html ?

Comment: @MuhammedGül Simple task like this doesn't need third party library.

Comment: Use `String` not `NSString` since the former is a true Swift class. Maybe you should pick an easier task if your goal is to learn Swift since you have given up so quickly or maybe read the documentation for `String` and see if you can make some more progress.

Comment: I want a value from html

Answer (score -1):

You can use this `JS` code to get the element from the `HTML`:

```
let js = "document.getElementsByClassName('Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)')[0].innerText"
```

or this if you need to set the element inside the `HTML`:

```
let js = "document.getElementsByClassName('Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)')[0].innerText = 'Any Value you want'"
```

Import `WebKit` and load the html into a webView

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let html = """
    </div></div><div class="My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"
    data-reactid="18"><div class="" data-reactid="19"><span
    class="Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)"
    data-reactid="20">9.62</span>
"""

    override func loadView() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self // Here is the Delegate
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

        self.view = webView
    }
}
```

Take the delegation and implement this method:

```
extension MyViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) {(result, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            print(String(describing: result))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to solve your issue and learn more about Swift and iOS or not? Let me know if this solves your issue or not

Comment: I could not make your code work, yet. I thought I could do this without JSON...now I have to understand the concept of Delegate etc. first.

Comment: What I don't get is...how do I load the html into the web view in your solution? I have it in the variable html right now....and then I don't get it transferred into the webview.

Comment: In this line: `webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)`. Your question needs some knowledge about these things. I couldn't offer something easier, Trust me.

Comment: Can you check my recent approach?

Answer (score -1):

So I worked out to write at least the first div-tag into a variable called element.
Now I want to narrow it down to the 9.62 in the html code. Can you support please?

```
@IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myUrlString = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LEO.DE?p=LEO.DE.tsrc=fin-srch"
    guard let myURL = URL(string: myUrlString) else { return }

    do{
        let myHtmlString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
        let htmlContent = myHtmlString

        do {
            let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent)

            do {
                let element = try doc.select("div").first()
                    print(element)
                do {
                    let text = try element?.text()
                    textlabel.text = text
                }
            } catch {

            } catch {

            }

        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of do-catches you can put `try!` on each line, if you're sure of the html though.

Comment: Do not post further questions in the answer section, this is not a discussion forum